# Express 4: After redirect i can't get my static file

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having troubles with Express 4 and static files. After a successful login i redirect my web-app to '/home/userId' but then, i get 404 on all static files. This is my router:

```
router.get('/home/:userid', function(req, res, next) {
  // TODO check if token is valid
 User.findById(req.params.userid).exec(function(err, find) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!find) {
      return res.json(utils.createErrorJsonResponse(404, "User not found!"));
    }
    return res.render('home', {
      title: 'Organizator',
      user: find
    });
  })
});
```

I think is not usefull show you my jade file, the only important thing is that there are lots of imported scripts, but just for give an example, this is how i load a css file:

```
  link(href='css/style.css', rel='stylesheet')
```

This is how i setup the static file

```
  app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public',{ maxAge: 86400000 }));
```

Where 'config.root' is my is:

```
path.normalize(__dirname + '/..')
```

As i said before if i connect to the basic page, so in my case:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

all my static files are imported, but as soon as i redirect i got 404. So how can i fix it? For example. I have a style file named 'style.css'. In the basic page ('http://localhost:3000) from the console i can see:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
```

Then from 'http://localhost:3000/home/':

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/home/css/style.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

So the problem is the '/home', but how can i "remove" it from static files request? Thank you.

Comment: How are you loading your files in JADE ? I think is important for your provided error. Are you doing link( href="/css/style.css") ?

Comment: Hi. I edited, has i said there no jade error, otherwise my basic page can't work

Comment: Make sure your href or src links starts with `/` so it looks like `/css/style.css` or `/js/some-file.js` without the initial `/` it's relative path and browser turns it into `/home/userId/css/style.css` which is not what you want.

Comment: As I suggest you in my comment your file is loading your files in JADE. @Molda has explained you the error more detailed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained well @Molda in comments, make sure your links start with `/`, otherwise the path will be relative to the actual route `http://localhost:3000/home`.